# winlogon, username and password

Tags: winlogon

I would like to extend the winlogon dialog to include an additional button that will write the username and password to the registry when the button is pressed.  Simply put, when the user presses the button to enable autologon, the registry is updated to flag this as an autologon system and to use these parameters (gathered from the two text boxes and the domain dropdown)

So my question is this...
does the winlogon application iteself handle the username, password and domain control, and then calls the gina.dll passing the value of the text boxes and drop down, or does the winlogon call the gina.dll and the gina.dll presents the dialog to enter the ensername and password?

this is for windows xp only - and in a very secured environment.

thanks